# Call function when block is initialized

Tags: ink, blocknumber

I want to call function on every block in ink smart contract?

So when new block is initialized, function is called automatically. Is that possible in ink?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, and this is one of the main differences between a "**Runtime**" execution model, and a "**Smart Contract**" execution model.

A Runtime is the core engine of the blockchain, and yields a lot of power to its developer. While risky in nature, one can write an [`on_initialize`](https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/frame_support/traits/trait.Hooks.html#method.on_initialize) hook and do what you have described.

A Smart Contract, on the other hand, is a shared execution environment that does nothing unless if someone interacts with the contract, and importantly pays all the gas fee. Therefore, such an API should also **NOT** be exposed in *any* smart contract language.

The equivalent of this would be to have an offchain bot of some sort that would trigger the contract on every block.

(I am not an expert in ink! per se, but I believe my answer holds about all smart contract execution environments.)